# Create CustomDBMSAutheticator using WLST

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I like to create new customdbmsauthenticator authentication provider to weblogic security realm using wlst python script. For default authenticator it is like

cmo.createAuthenticationProvider("MyProvider","weblogic.security.providers.authentication.DefaultAuthenticator")

but which class is for customdbmsauthenticator instead of weblogic.security.providers.authentication.DefaultAuthenticator?

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for is `weblogic.security.providers.authentication.CustomDBMSAuthenticator`

Comment: Thanks. Do you know, is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Not really. LDAP authenticators classes are available in this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13715/config_wls.htm#WLSTG251). One way is to find them from their [mbean](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/security/providers/authentication/package-summary.html).